# Can Docker map multiple container ports to one host port?

Tags: docker, docker-network

Based on my understanding port mapping is 1 to 1, what I don't understand is why the data structure used for port mapping in container data is like this,

```
"NetworkSettings": {
[...]
"Ports": {
    "8888/tcp": [
        {
            "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
            "HostPort": "8888"
        }
    ]
}
```

The `"8888/tcp"` key maps to a list instead of single object. Thus in a Java client the data structure for Ports is like this `Map<String, List<PortBinding>>`, but the `List` here can only contain 1 element right? Or did I terribly miss something fundamental?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is perfectly legal:

`docker run -tid -p 8080:80 -p 8090:80 nginx`

```
"Ports": {
            "443/tcp": null,
            "80/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "8090"
                },
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "8080"
                }
            ]
        }
```

So no, it's not 1 to 1.

Comment: Is it is possible to map multiple docker ports to 1 host port?

Answer (score 3):

johnharris85 's answer is correct. Here, I want to points out that you can map multiple host ports to the same container port and the opposite is impossible(except they have different IP address). Just think about how can the postman deliver things to two houses, with the same house number.

Answer (score 1):

So, you want one incoming connection to become a connection to two back end services. That can't be done at all: it is incompatible with the semantics of having a connection.

But what you can do, is have a system in which some connections go to one back end and other connections go to a different back end. That needs a reverse proxy connected to the host port, which then forwards to the back end service: multiple containers.

You also have to be clear how the reverse proxy decides which back end service to forward to: why do you want that functionality at all. The two choices are: load balancing, and fan out. For load balancing, the connections are shared out so you get the performance boost of having multiple back end servers. For fan out, you have the back end server used decided according to the URL requested.

The most popular HTTP proxies are Apache Httpd and Nginx.